# C++ program hangs due to a `uint32_t` for-loop

Tags: c++

I have the following program (this is it in its entirety, except comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void sieve(uint32_t n) {
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(uint32_t j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
    }
  }
}

int main(int argv, char * argc[]) {
  sieve(10);
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles just fine. When I run it, it just hangs forever. Even if I put `std::cout << "Test"` as the first line in `main`, it never prints.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: How did your test result conclude that it hangs _forever_? ;)

Comment: I used a proof by exaggeration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for(uint32_t j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {`

First time through `i` is 0 and so `j` doesn't actually change (`j += 0`) ==> infinite loop

Comment: Beat me to it.. It froze my computer when i ran it ... Lessons Learned